# Webscraping using beautiful soup giving multiple results

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am scraping [this][1] page and want the cell phone numbers of the agent.

I am using this script

```
# phone num
        phonenum=soup.select(".phone-content")

        for a in phonenum:
            print a.text.strip().encode("utf-8")
```

but it gives the phone number multiple time. I dont know why. how can i limit it to one phone number only?
[1]: http://dubai.dubizzle.com/property-for-rent/residential/apartmentflat/2014/2/2/do-you-want-to-live-in-amazing-views-of-bu-2-3/?back=ZHViYWkuZHViaXp6bGUuY29tL3Byb3BlcnR5LWZvci1yZW50L3Jlc2lkZW50aWFsL2FwYXJ0bWVudGZsYXQv&pos=1

Comment: Note that there are two identical phone numbers in two phone-content classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The page you're scraping has two elements with the class `phone-content`. That's why you're getting two phone numbers. You can pass a more specific CSS selector to the `.select` method:

```
phonenum=soup.select("#listing-reply-controls .phone-content")
```

As an alternative you can remove the duplicate phone numbers:

```
phonenum=soup.select(".phone-content")
# set comprehension will remove the duplicate phone numbers
unique_phonenum = {p.text.strip().encode("utf-8") for p in phonenum}

for a in unique_phonenum:
    print a
```